# How to hot export the configuration of an ActiveMQ Artemis and hot import it?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I want to make a hot export of the configuration, in order to be able to import it later, without stopping the machine:

- address
- queue
- routing type
- address-settings
- etc...

The creation of the queues is done via the Apache ActiveMQ interface, Management Console.

I know that we can perform an export, however Apache Artemis must be stopped:

```
#Export the log in XML format
./artemis data exp > /tmp/export.xml

#Import of the log in XML format
./artemis data imp --input /tmp/export.xml --host localhost --port 61617
```

I know we can do an export via logs too, however Apache Artemis must be Stop:

```
artemis data print --journal D:\apache-artemis-2.6.2\instances\broker-sandbox-miscellaneous\datajournal\ > D:/2022-02-05_ResultPrintJournal.txt
```

Is there any way to recover the configuration, and import it afterwards on the fly ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to dump the configuration of the items you mentioned at runtime and then apply them to another running broker.

Instead of modifying the broker via the web console you could change `broker.xml`. That way all the configuration changes would be captured in a simple format and you could simply copy that to another broker.